# Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2'

Tags: ruby

Versions

- ruby 1.9.2-p290
- rails 3.0.9
- mysql2-0.2.13 under rvm
- ubuntu 11.04

gem installed with "gem install mysql2 -v '< 0.3' ". All dependencies were met.

rails & 'rails c' are working fine.

I need to run a script outside of rails environment using activerecord 3.0.9. When I run the script this is the output:

======================

```
/home/ross/work/x/library/models.rb:27:in `eval': !!! Missing the mysql2 gem. Add it to your Gemfile: gem 'mysql2' (RuntimeError)
    from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:19:in `mysql_connection'
    from /home/ross/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.0.9/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:229:in `new_connection' ....
```

=======================

Clearly the gem is there, because rails works.

Don't know why the gem isn't found when running a script?

Can anyone pls shed some light on the issue?

Regards
Ross

Answer (score 24):

In case it helps anyone, in my case I had forgotten to change the adapter in `database.yml` to `mysql2` for the production database, the `Gemfile` was OK (upgrading from `rails` 2.3.4 to 3.0.9).

Answer (score 16):

Check your `database.yml` first

You have something like this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  ...
```

To solve your problem you need replace `mysql` to `mysql2`.

Correct version of `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2 
  encoding: utf8
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was my problem. I was using a different database.yml  for the ruby scripts and had forgotten to update from mysql to mysql2 in that version of the yml. Thank you for your prompt help. Ross